# Ubuntu 14.04 Delay when switching window focus using SDL2 and vsync

Tags: ubuntu, sdl-2, vsync

I'm learning the basics of SDL2 and when I run my program (vsync, windowed), there is a delay when switching focus between windows and dragging windows is laggy. This applies to all windows, not just the SDL2 application. When vsync is not enabled, all windows behave smoothly, as expected.

I am running ubuntu 14.04, using a nvidia card, driver version 349.12. Below is a minimum working example that reproduces the behaviour on my machine.

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

void init(bool vsync);

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    init(true);

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

        SDL_Rect fillRect = {SCREEN_WIDTH/4, SCREEN_HEIGHT/4, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2};
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF); //RGBA
        SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &fillRect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }


    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    gRenderer = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();


    return 0;
}

void init(bool vsync) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1");

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (vsync) {
        gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    } else {
        gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    }
}
```

Running this code on a second machine (14.04, bumblebee drivers) produces smooth window behaviour both with and without vsync. I have also tried numerous games with and without vsync and the only one that reproduces the behaviour is FTL (which I believe is an SDL game).

How can I fix this/debug further?